# .file problem in home folder

Tags: files, filemanager

hi dear friends ins start sorry for bad english .. Im after install one application in my system after install this app listed in home file sample 
hom/jhon 
.skype .gimp .gedit

how to solve this

[image]

Comment: Those .file are ok. Many apps do that. Because they keep your settings. Just keep those files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are hidden files and folders. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and they will hide.